# Accessing variables inside jenkins pipeline closure body

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a pipeline shared library to create a workspace hash so that we avoid path length problems on our windows builds:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

def call(body) {
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config

    ws(getWsHash(config.length ?: 10)) {
        body()
    }
}

def getWsHash(length) {
    def md5Hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest("${env.JOB_NAME}_${env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER}".bytes).encodeHex().toString()
    return md5Hash.substring(0,10)
}
```

which I want to use like this:

```
node('windows') {

    wsHash {
        stage('Checkout') {
            checkout scm
        }

        stage('Build') {
            bat '.\\src\\Build.cmd'
        }
    }
}
```

However this fails because the `scm` variable is null. I have managed to fix it by changing to this:

```
node('windows') {

    def scm = scm

    wsHash {
        stage('Checkout') {
            checkout scm
        }

        stage('Build') {
            bat '.\\src\\Build.cmd'
        }
    }
}
```

However this is both clunky and doesn't work for all instances. For example we also use artifactory and when trying to use this:

```
def server = Artifactory.server('advancedcsg')
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method server() on null object

If I try the "trick" by doing:

```
def Artifactory = Artifactory
```

I get this exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Refusing to marshal org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl for security reasons

Can someone help explain what's going on here and what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Jenkins pipeline scripts, but with Groovy knowledge and what you describe, the problem is that you give the closure to `wsHash` and there set the delegate to an empty map (`config`), so `scm` is requested from it and and returns `null` of course.

I guess if you name the `it` parameter of the node closure explicitly and use that it should work, like:

```
node('windows') { windowsNode ->
    wsHash {
        stage('Checkout') {
            checkout windowsNode.scm
        }

        stage('Build') {
            bat '.\\src\\Build.cmd'
        }
    }
}
```

The other error you get, the `Refusing to marshal` error is most likely due to another part in your pipeline where you have something like `"foo $bar baz"` which is a `GString` and you need a `String` instead, so use `"foo $bar baz" as String` instead and the dynamic parts will be resolved immediately and transformed to a plain `String` object.